# can we define our own bins in histogram of pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, histogram, visualization

I am wondering if this is possible actually I have a dataset and I wanted to plot histogram on the basis of my own defined bins as we do in math, finding interval then we used to plot on it, although the system generated bins also do well but I wonder if this is possible I would like to familiar to that

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to bins. You can do something like the following:

```
plt.hist(data, bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100])
```